# Show/Add an Item from/to Some ComboBoxs in C++ Builder XE8

Tags: c++, delphi, combobox, c++builder

I need your help to resolve my 2 problems.

I'm using 3 ComboBoxs (CB). When choosing an item from 1st CB, then an item of 2nd & 3rd CB will automatically come up .

On Delphi, all settings are work so well via "Text" property.

1st CB contains:

```
Google
Yahoo
```

2nd CB contains:

```
8.8.8.8
9.9.9.9
```

3rd CB contains:

```
8888
9999
```

Below is my code on Delphi :

```
procedure TForm.1stCBChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if 1stCB.Text  = 'Google' then begin
    2ndCB.Text := '8.8.8.8';
    3rdCB.Text := '8888';
 end else
 if 1stCB.Text  = 'Yahoo' then begin
    2ndCB.Text := '9.9.9.9';
    3rdCB.Text := '9999';
 end;
end;
```

The problem is that on C++ Builder XE8, it's not work properly via "Text" property. On the other words, the 2nd & 3rd CB's item is not shown via "Text" property.

```
void __fastcall TForm::1stCBChange(TObject *Sender)
{
  if (1stCBChange->Text == "Google")
   {
     2ndCB->Text = "8.8.8.8";
     3rdCB->Text = "8888";
   }
  else 
  if (1stCBChange->Text == "Yahoo")
   {
     2ndCB->Text = "9.9.9.9";
     3rdCB->Text = "9999";
   }
}
```

So to make it works, I have to use "ItemIndex" property.

```
void __fastcall TForm::1stCBChange(TObject *Sender)
{
  if (1stCBChange->ItemIndex == 0)
   {
     2ndCB->ItemIndex = IntToStr(0); 
     // or 2ndCB->ItemIndex = 0;
     3rdCB->ItemIndex = IntToStr(0);
   }
  else 
  if (1stCBChange->ItemIndex == 1)
   {
     2ndCB->ItemIndex = IntToStr(1);
     3rdCB->ItemIndex = IntToStr(1);
   }
}
```

I've tried some ways, but not works, e.g. `2ndCB->Items->Objects[1] = (TObject*) new String("8.8.8.8");` or `2ndCB->Items->AddObject("8.8.8.8",2ndCB);` so on and on...

So my question: how to make it works on C++ Builder XE8 via "Text" option really like on Delphi ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Which `==` is used when you compare a delphi string and a C string? I bet it the delphi string is converted to a C string and then pointers compared.

Comment: Btw, you are expected to ask one question at a time. You asked two.

Comment: My 2nd question was solved by using, e.g.`1stCB->Items->Insert(0, "BlaBla");`. Btw, I am a newcomer in c ++ , so my knowledge is very limited indeed. Thank you...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the `Text` property returns a `System::String` object, which has an overridden `operator==()` for `String` values, and `String` has non-explicit constructors for both `char*` and `wchar_t*` strings. Thus `if (1stCBChange->Text == "Google")` is performing `if (1stCBChange->Text.operator==(String("Google")))`

Comment: @Remy: I also want to thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your first problem: you probably don't have the same `Style` property on the Combobox in Delphi and C++Builder. Setting it to `csDropDown` allows you to specify the Text, but `csDropDownList` doesn't.

Now, ItemIndex is an integer property, so the call to IntToStr is not needed. It shouldn't even compile, as you can't assign text to an integer variable, and in XE5 at least it doesn't. If it works later it must be because there is an `operator int()` or similar for UnicodeString, although I didn't find it on the latest documentation.

About your second issue: `Add()` adds the passed string to the end of the list. If you want to insert the string in a specific position, then you need to call `Insert()` which asks you for the position to insert it, in your case it would be 0. This, of course, assumes the StringList is not sorted.

Here is the Documentation for `TStrings`: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TStrings

Comment: Resolved. By the way, it is really can't be exactly as simple Delphi's syntax. But everything was done in a way: `if (Host->ItemIndex == Host->Items->IndexOf("Google"))` so on... Thank you, all.

Comment: There is no "automatic conversion from UnicodeString to integer".

Comment: @July:  Both Delphi and C++Builder use the **exact same** RTL/VCL/FMX libraries, so the **exact same logic** can be used in both languages if the ComboBoxes are configured the **exact same way** in both languages.  That is clearly not the case in your situation, or else you would not be having this much trouble. Make sure your ComboBox properties in C++Builder match the same properties in Delphi.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, it was a poor choice of words from my part. I'll edit the answer to use the correct idea.